# Does Asp.net Web API 2.2 OData4 support group by clause?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, odata, aggregate, asp.net-web-api2

Does Asp.net Web API 2.2 OData4 support aggregates and groupby clause?
I could not find any conclusive answer to this .

Comment: A simple answer should be no. But can you provide more detailed requirements so that maybe there are some alternatives.

Comment: And to make it clear, OData V4 has http:/docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata-data-aggregation-ext/v4.0/odata-data-aggregation-ext-v4.0.pdf the spec for aggregation and it will be supported in the future.

Comment: Thanks @QianLi : My requirement is simple to be able to execute aggregation functions(sum,min etc.) and impose group by clause over them.I just want to have some thing out of the box(from web api).

Comment: Also,what are the alternatives?

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to implement your service using the `QueryByCube` linq extension method provided by the [AdaptiveLINQ](http://www.adaptivelinq.com) component.

For example:

```
[EnableQuery]
public IQueryable<SalesCubeItem> Get()
{
     return DataContext.OrderDetails.QueryByCube(new SalesCubeDefinition());
}
```

where `SalesCubeDefinition` define:

- 2 dimensions: `ProductName` and `CustomerName`
- 2 measures: `Sales`, `Quantity`

you can query the *sales per customer* using the OData protocol like this:

```
http://.../salesAnalysis?$select=CustomerName,Sales
```

or *quantity sold by product*:

```
http://.../salesAnalysis?$select=ProductName,Quantity
```

and of course you can combine this with other OData operators ($filter, $orderby...)

Disclaimer: I'm the AdaptiveLINQ developer

Comment: Thankyou, to me this was an obvious omission from the entity framework overall, I started to switch over to an Azure Search API solution to get this sort of info with facets but this satisfies most of my current API requirements. But ah it's a hard sell to my team as a licensed solution