# Does OData v4 understand Dimensions, Measures and Cubes

Tags: odata, asp.net-web-api2, dimensions, cubes, measures

I am building an OData Web Service using WebAPI and OData v4.

I am wondering if this new version of OData is capable of understanding Dimension, Measures and Cubes and is able to execute Queries from the data.

How would I be able to configure that?

Comment: What do you mean by "dimension, measures, cubes"? Can you give more details or your scenarios so that others can better understand your questions.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26020725/does-asp-net-web-api-2-2-odata4-support-group-by-clause

Answer (score 0):

From the [Overview](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata01/os/complete/part1-protocol/odata-v4.0-errata01-os-part1-protocol-complete.html#_Toc399426695) of the protocol spec you can see that:

> Towards that end, the OData Protocol follows these design principles: Prefer mechanisms that work on a variety of data stores. In particular, **do not assume a relational data model**.

So there isn't anything preventing you from modelling cube data using OData.

One way that I can think of is to consider every entity set as a cube, in which some properties & navigation properties of each entity are the dimensions it has. And it has a bunch of measure properties as its measures. Thus, by querying the entity set, you get the whole cube. And you can use some simple query to query it:

```
GET http://host/service/Cube?$select=Dimension1,Dimension2,Measure1 & $filter=Measure1 gt 100
```

This is only my own simple model. For more complicated cube representation and queryability, OData V4 has this aggregation extension to help you better modelling it. You can have a look at this [example data model](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata-data-aggregation-ext/v4.0/cs01/odata-data-aggregation-ext-v4.0-cs01.html#_Toc378326286) it has to modelling cube data.

Comment: I don't think the ODataLib supports aggregation as of yet:

https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/1786

It appears to be a work-in-progress.

Thanks anyway

Comment: @FrancescoFerraioli There is a pull request for the ODataLib on Github about aggregation: https://github.com/OData/odata.net/pull/6

Comment: Awesome! Do you know when that will be available?

Comment: @FrancescoFerraioli Most possibly not near. But you can always monitor through https://github.com/OData/odata.net/milestones

Answer (score 0):

Using the LINQ extension method `QueryByCube` provide by the [AdaptiveLINQ](http://www.adaptivelinq.com) component, you can develop a **queryable analysis service**.

Sample LINQ query using `QueryByCube`:

```
dataContext.MyEntitySet.QueryByCube(myCube)
    .Where(x => x.Measure1 > 100)
    .Select(x => new {
       Dimension1 = x.Dimension1,
       Dimension2 = x.Dimension2,
       Measure1 = x.Meeasure1
    })
```

`QueryByCube` acts as a (queryable) *view with implicit aggregations*.

Cube dimensions and measures are defined as C# expression. `myCube` is a instance of a class implementing the `AdaptiveLINQ.ICubeDefinition<>` interface.

```
public class MyCubeDefinition : ICubeDefinition<MySourceClass, MyCubeItem>
{
  static public readonly Expression<Func<MySourceClass, string>>
    Dimension1 = item => ...
  static public readonly Expression<Func<MySourceClass, string>>
    Dimension2 = item => ...
  static public readonly Expression<Func<IEnumerbale<MySourceClass>, string>>
    Measure1 = items => ...
}
```

**`QueryByCube` transforms the query (based on a semantic analysis to determine the dimensions to be used) in order to use the `GroupBy` operator and return an `IQueryable` collection.**

To expose the cube as a queryable HTTP service, implement an ASP.Net WebAPI ODataController like this:

```
public class MyCubeController : ODataController
{
  public MyCubeController()
  {
    // get dataContext
    ...
  }

  static MyCubeDefinition MyCube = new MyCubeDefinition();

  [EnableQuery]
  public IQueryable<MyCubeItem> Get()
  {
      return dataContext.MyEntitySet.QueryByCube(myCube);       
  }
}
```

Now you can query your cube like this:

*Mesaure1 per Dimension1*

```
http://.../MyCube?$select=Dimension1, Measure1
```

*Mesaure1 per (Dimension1, Dimension2)*

```
http://.../MyCube?$select=Dimension1, Dimension2, Measure1
```

*Mesaure1 per (Dimension1, Dimension2) order by Mesaure1, top 5*

```
http://.../MyCube?$select=Dimension1, Dimension2, Measure1&$orderby=Measure1&$top=5
```

**Disclaimer:** I'm the AdaptiveLINQ developer

Comment: Yeah i've seen this type of answer before, thanks. But this doesn't allow for the client to request the type of query, its defined server side, correct? Also, what is myCube. Im guessing dataSet is the IQueryable<T>.

Comment: @Francesco I've complete my answer. The client decide the dimensions to consider and the measures to compute just by using the $select OData operator.